# SQL Server Full Text Search Index update takes a while

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently using full text search on a table. However when updating the full text columns it takes several seconds to update.

For example:

```
UPDATE
    TestTable
SET
    TestColumn = 'Cats'
WHERE
    Id = 'a'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    TestTable
WHERE
    CONTAINS(TestColumn, 'Cats') AND
    Id = 'A'
```

The above query will return 0 results, yet if I wait for 3 seconds and run the code again, I will get results:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TestTable
WHERE
    CONTAINS(TestColumn, 'Cats') AND
    Id = 'A'
```

Is there any way around this? Is there any way to delay the code until the Full Text Index has finished updating?

I have found similar questions on here with no answers:

[Allocate more resources for Full-Text search index population service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761651/allocate-more-resources-for-full-text-search-index-population-service)

Comment: This question isn't really about programming.  You'd probably get an answer if you asked at https://dba.stackexchange.com/.